# Threading - close while loop

Tags: python, loops, python-multithreading

I have a while loop:

```
while True:
    x = threading.Timer(3, something)
    x.start()
    # whatever
    x.cancel()
```

I want `something` to be a function or something to close the loop automatically if the timer runs out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "close the loop automatically"? The only two ways I can think of are by executing a `break` or raising an exception.

Comment: I mean to stop the loop from executing further. In the threading.Timer, you can't pass `break` or `raise WhateverError` because they contain keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `threading.Timer` creates a thread, you could do something like this to generate a fake `KeyboardInterrupt` to interrupt the loop:

```
from time import sleep
import threading
import _thread as thread  # Low-level threading API


def something():
    thread.interrupt_main()  # Raises KeyboardInterrupt.

try:
    while True:
        print('loop iteration started')
        x = threading.Timer(3, something)
        x.start()
        sleep(4)
        x.cancel()
        print('loop iteration completed')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('timeout occurred - loop closed')

print('-fini-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, to cancel generic while loops:

```
global_flag = True
 
def something():
    global_flag = False

while global_flag:
    x = threading.Timer(3, something)
    x.start()
    input("hello! >")
    x.cancel()
```

Comment: Two problems: one, the `something()` function doesn't have a global, and also, it works, it only closes once you've put in an input.